# Selenium: Element Click Intercepted while submitting a form

Tags: python, selenium

So I'm trying to submit a form but something is either preventing me from accessing the box or I'm using a wrong element but I think I'm using the correct one.

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = 'mypath/chromedriver.exe') 
driver.maximize_window()
#driver.implicitly_wait(50)
driver.get("https://ai.fmcsa.dot.gov/SMS")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@title='Close']"))).click()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="home-body"]/div[1]/div/div[1]/form/label').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="home-body"]/div[1]/div/div[1]/form/label').send_keys('1818437')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/article/section[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/form/input[2]').click();
```

What I'm getting on the output is

> ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted:
> Element ... is
> not clickable at point (553, 728). Other element would receive the
> click: 
> (Session info: chrome=93.0.4577.63)

What might be the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things to noted down in this scenario :-

1. When you define an explicit waits `wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)`, you can always use `wait reference` in the scope. you *do not need* to create *again and again* in same class.
2. Try to avoid absolute **xpath** `/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/article/section[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/form/input[2]`, try with relative xpath/xpath axes.
3. When we try to send keys to some element, in general it should be a input tag, not `label`
4. You may have to scroll, may be not in this case but when you scroll manually to interact with elements in UI, same has to automated with Selenium as well.
5. Also I observed to this webapp that search and input tags are duplicated, so I have used xpath indexing `[2]` to handle.

**Sample code :-**

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = 'mypath/chromedriver.exe') 
driver.maximize_window()
#driver.implicitly_wait(50)
driver.get("https://ai.fmcsa.dot.gov/SMS")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@title='Close']"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "(//input[@name='MCSearch'])[2]"))).send_keys('1818437')
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "(//input[@name='search'])[2]"))).click()
```

Comment: I really appreciate the tips! Is there a way, by chance, to do this scraping without actually having the code open an instance of Chrome? Like, running it in the background

Comment: @alexb  : yes there's a headless mode. Do try it out.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below `xpaths` too.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='sms-search-box']//input[1]").send_keys('1818437')
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='sms-search-box']//input[2]").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Xpath you are using is not right. Your xpath for the input field should be like this.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='MCSearch' and @placeholder='Type Name or U.S. DOT#']").send_keys("1818437")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@placeholder='Type Name or U.S. DOT#']//following::input[@value='Search']").click();
```